# aspx 2 razor code conversion

Tags: razor

Can anyone convert the following code to Razor, i tried telerik aspx 2tazor, but thats not working. when I use captcha with aspx its working, but i dont know how to convert the below code to make it work for razor.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MvcApplication1.Models.CaptchaData>" %>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Please provide your name and a comment</legend>
    <p>
        <%: Html.XCaptcha().Image(m => m.EncrypedSolution) %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="Attempt">
            Characters above</label>
        <%=Html.TextBoxFor(cd => cd.Attempt)%><%=Html.ValidationMessageFor(cd => cd.Attempt)%>
    </p>
    <%: Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary() %>
</fieldset>
</div>
<script src="../../Scripts/xcaptcha-2.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body> </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried http://razorconverter.codeplex.com/?

I too have been investigating how to convert an existing site with aspx to have Razor views and this tool has helped a lot. It isn't perfect, and it doesn't get you 100% of the way there but it does help you save time converting files.

The approach I found helped me in getting the most out of this tool was to create two asp.net mvc websites...one with ASPX and the other with Razor...then I used the tool to convert the aspx site...and then compared the results with the Razor site which helped me spot what additional steps I needed to follow in order to fully switch over to Razor. I plan to use that learning experience to convert an existing website...

One disadvantage I found with this tool (and maybe there is a way to avoid this that I am not aware of) is that it  creates all your cshtml files as lowercase files rather than keeping the camel case...

Another disadvantage is that it seems to leave @(...) around lots of lines of code...but they are easily removed.

One nice thing is that this tool also converts your Site.Mastor which you will then have to rename to _Layout.cshtml

The result for the razor converter for your code is:

```
    @model MvcApplication1.Models.CaptchaData

<fieldset>
    <legend>Please provide your name and a comment</legend>
    <p>
        @(Html.XCaptcha().Image(m => m.EncrypedSolution))
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="Attempt">
            Characters above</label>
        @(Html.TextBoxFor(cd => cd.Attempt))@(Html.ValidationMessageFor(cd => cd.Attempt))
    </p>
    @(Html.AntiForgeryToken())
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
    @(Html.ValidationSummary())
</fieldset>
</div>
<script src="../../Scripts/xcaptcha-2.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body> </html>
```

Another tool that I have found useful is [WebFormsRazorConverterVsExtension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d2bfd1ca-9808-417c-b963-eb1ea4896790)

It utilizes [Telerik's razor-converter](https://github.com/telerik/razor-converter) under the hood...and although you said that wasn't working out for you, when I used it to convert your sample, it worked out great for me...so maybe you should give it a try.

It doesn't convert Site.Master...so you may need to use a combination of both of these tools to get your site converted...but the output is cleaner than razorconverter above...

Here is the result I get when I use the WebFormsRazorConverterVsExtension:

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.CaptchaData

<fieldset>
    <legend>Please provide your name and a comment</legend>
    <p>
        @Html.XCaptcha().Image(m => m.EncrypedSolution)
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="Attempt">
            Characters above</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(cd => cd.Attempt)@Html.ValidationMessageFor(cd => cd.Attempt)
    </p>
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
</fieldset>
</div>
<script src="../../Scripts/xcaptcha-2.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body> </html>
```

Also, I found the following references helpful and so they may help you doing the conversion.

- http://www.beletsky.net/2011/07/switching-from-aspx-to-razor-view.html
- http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx